How to embed my youtube channel videos and their titles automatic to website
I have a Youtube channel and I could able to add those video to website automatically but I want to add the title below the video this part I could not able to achieve can any one help me with this. Thanks
I have tried this and could auto add video but I also want to add the video title in h1 below it.
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?
        listType=playlist&list=UUlbIlkP6078-DapTSPwYy7Q&index=2"></iframe>

